# problems with the tag that show information in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with the tag that show information in *AngularJS*,  because when i use the tag `ng-bind` it works well, but when i use this tag `{{}}` it doesn't work.

**Code:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="static/app/public/js/angular.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="static/app/js/app.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="ClientListCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Actif</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="c in clients">
            <td >{{c.id}}</td>
            <td>{{c.nom}}</td>
            <td>{{c.age}}</td>
            <td>{{c.date_creation|date:'d/M/y'}}</td>
            <td >{{c.actif}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what problem are you facing here ?

Comment: Can you share your JavaScript code as well for me to understand and provide a right solution

Comment: add your code here https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what problem you did faced. I was able to run your code properly, both with `ng-bind` and with Angular Expressions `{{}}`.

Refer the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/jfc87nxu/).

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ClientListCtrl">
  <h3>
With "ng-bind"
</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in clients">
      <td ng-bind="c.id"></td>
      <td ng-bind="c.nom"></td>
      <td ng-bind="c.age"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <br />
  <h3>
With "Angular expressions"
</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in clients">
      <td>{{c.id}}</td>
      <td>{{c.nom}}</td>
      <td>{{c.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ClientListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.clients = [{
    'id': 1,
    'nom': 'Abc',
    'age': 20
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'nom': 'Pqr',
    'age': 43
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'nom': 'Xyz',
    'age': 32
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'nom': 'Def',
    'age': 67
  }]
});
```

Comment: @Aaron, check out the *demo* in the post, it worked well with both.

Comment: thank you Mr Shashank for your response ,the ng-bind already worked to me but this tag {{}} doesn't ,perhaps the problem is django because now i use django to dilever the list of clients

Comment: @Rarche, since you neither mentioned about Django nor tagged it, how would one be able to find out the root cause of it. With all information, that you provided, it worked pretty well for me. Anyways, figure it out or continue to use `ng-bind`. Happy Coding!!!